# how the warning Possible data overrun for function 'memcpy' happens and how to fix it?

Tags: c, arrays, memcpy

I have the following code:

```
#define NUM_PEOPLE 20
#define TIME_PEOPLE 10
typedef struct
{
    int name;
    int age;
} People

typedef struct
{
    int number;
    int post;
} Contact;

typedef struct
{
      int             number;
      Pepole          people[TIME_PEOPLE][NUM_PEOPLE];
      Contact         contact[NUM_PEOPLE];
} Master;

typedef struct
{
      int             number;
      People          people[NUM_PEOPLE][NUM_PEOPLE];
      Contact         contact[NUM_PEOPLE];
} Info;

Info info;
Master master;

int counter = 1
int size;
int offset = 0;

while(counter > 0)
{  

      size = TIME_PEOPLE;

      if(counter == 1)
      {
     size = NUM_PEOPLE - (TIME_PEOPLE * (offset + 1));
      }

      memcpy(&info.people[TIME_PEOPLE + TIME_PEOPLE * offset][0], &master.people[0][0],
         sizeof(People) * size * NUM_PEOPLE);
      offset ++;
      counter --;
}
```

but I got the following warning:

```
Warning 669: Possible data overrun for function 'memcpy(void *, const void *, unsigned int)', argument 3 ,
```

I made this code, because `NUM_PEOPLE` could be changed to less than `TIME_PEOPLE`, then how this warning happens and how to fix it?

P.S. If `TIME_PEOPLE` be changed to `8`, this means we need to copy three times to fullfill the `info`

Comment: Not sure if it's causing your warning, but two obvious problems: `People` is misspelled in you `Master` structure declaration, and `offset` is never set (you should have gotten a "use before set" warning). Generally speaking, though, I tend to use `memmove()` rather than `memcpy()`.

Comment: I modified the offset part, the initial value is 0

Comment: This exact code and question is asked and answered in other posts. Must be a homework assignment...

Comment: no, it is not, the warning is different, and it is not a homework assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider what happens when offset is incremented to one. This reference:

```
&info.people[TIME_PEOPLE + TIME_PEOPLE * offset][0]
```

translates to this:

```
&info.people[20][0]
```

And since the `info.people` array only has `NUM_PEOPLE` (i.e. 20) elements, that is already pointing past the end.

Given the way the code is currently written, that will never happen since the loop is only ever executed once, but the compiler might not take that into account. What is the point of having that loop if it's only ever going to be executed once and the offset will only ever be zero?

It looks to me like that array reference should really have been:

```
&info.people[TIME_PEOPLE * offset][0]
```

The size calculation should have been:

```
size = NUM_PEOPLE - (TIME_PEOPLE * offset);
```

And the counter should probably have been initialised to something like this:

```
int counter = ceil((float)NUM_PEOPLE/TIME_PEOPLE);
```

But it's hard to say without knowing exactly what you're trying to do. I just know that what you currently have implemented doesn't make any sense.

Comment: but can this remove the warning?

Comment: @user2131316 Maybe. I'd suggest you try it out and see. My compiler doesn't produce a warning with the original code so I can only guess what your compiler would do.

Comment: @user2131316 Are you able to get rid of that warning?

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of 'offset' ? You're using for 10+10 * offset for a base address on your destination. It looks like info.people[] is only 20 to begin with.

Also, 10 + 10 * offset may compute as 10 + (10 * offset). Be safe: use (10+10)*offset

Comment: May compute as?  It has certainly better, or the compiler's broken.

Comment: I don't know what sort of compiler you're using. There are broken compilers.